# Laravel eloquent relationship not accessing second table

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables:

emails: email_id, name

email_templates: template_id, template_mid, template_lang, template_subject, template_mail

Template_mid is foreign key and associated with emails.id

My models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Email extends Model
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Indicates primary key column.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $primaryKey = "email_id";

    public function template()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Email_template', 'template_mid', 'email_id');
    }
}
```

Email_template

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Email_template extends Model
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Indicates primary key column.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $primaryKey = "template_id";
}
```

When I run this in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {

        $emails = Email::all();
        dd($emails);
    }
```

I cannot access the the template method and I have only id, subject in the dumped results. How can I fix this?

Comment: `$this->hasOne('App\Email_template', 'template_mid', 'id');`

Comment: the column is email_id not id

Comment: Also, the templates won't load automatically. You can load them with `Email::with('template')->all();` or individually with `$email->template`

Comment: I tried dd($email->template) but it says Property [template] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Try `foreach($emails as $email) { dd($email->template); }`. You can't pull it from the collection, but you should be able to pull it from the individual email records.

Comment: thanks thats working! Also I wanted to add global scope for `template_lang = $_SESSION['lang']` Should I declare it in email_template model?

Comment: That's more of a personal preference. I probably wouldn't use a session variable in a model, but that's just me.

Comment: But should I declare the global scope in Email_template model? btw you can post it as answer so I can accept it

Comment: got it working thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related models are not loaded automatically. You can either load them with `with()`, or individually:

```
Email::with('template')->get();
```

or

```
foreach($emails as $email) 
{ 
      dd($email->template); 
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify the second was working for me. The first says: BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all does not exist.

Comment: at the end should be `->get();` I think

Comment: Oh, right, that should be `get()`, not `all()`. I'll fix that.